# Rust-gdb layout src does not show the source code

Tags: rust, gdb

I'm new to rust and rust-gdb.
When debugging a rust application (which is built with debug symbols) with rust-gdb,
layout src does not show any source code.

The strange thing is that, when I enter `list`, source code appears and disappears quickly.
Does any one know why this happens?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing a [example], and the output you get. Please copy the text as such in the question, do not post screenshots.

Comment: Maybe you need a gdb update. What version do you have?

Comment: Thanks, I found the reason, and it was the problem of the rustc version. After I updated rustc to 1.52.1, the gdb worked fine.